# Как вывести простое сообщение Yii2 "Hello World"

Tags: yii2

Как вывести простое сообщение Yii. Работаю на локалке.

код контролера SiteController

```
namespace app\controllers;
use yii\web\Controller;
class SiteController extends Controller
{
public function actionHelloworld()
{
    return 'Hello World';
}
}
```

Comment: Вроде все верно. Что не работает?

Comment: Вот Вам [руководство](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/tree/master/docs/guide-ru) на русском, а вот его [раздел про *hello-world*](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/start-hello.md).
Успехов в изучении!

Comment: Я изучаю, более сложные задачи решаю, а эту не понимаю как вывести.

Comment: К тому же то, что вы предлагаете,  это через views пример, а тут напрямую, как-то вывести можно.

Comment: Какая должна быть ссылка, что бы вывелось сообщение Hello World

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена нужно было формировать запрос от пользователя в ссылке с маленькой буквы

ссылка http://localhost/basic/web/index.php?r=site/helloworld